# Is there anyway to remove a Route or Polyline on the MAPS in Appcelerator

Tags: routes, maps, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I need to remove the route or poylines I created on the maps. I couldn't achieved to do that. I couldn't find any explanation on how to do that in the documentation. Is there anyway or I have to re-create the maps object everytime?

```
var kuzeyYol = Map.createRoute({
    name:'guzergah',
    width: 4,
    color: 'green',
    points: noktalar
});

harita.addRoute(kuzeyYol);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `removeRoute` and `removePolygon` method that takes the route or polygon to remove as the first and single argument.